# How to change cursorline color when changing to command mode

Tags: neovim, autocmd

This code changes the cursorline color when in insert, normal and replace mode at least but doesn't really work in visual mode and doesn't work at all in command mode. Whats wrong?

```
function Pain()
local colors = {
    bg = "#202328",
    fg = "#bbc2cf",
    yellow = "#ECBE7B",
    cyan = "#008080",
    darkblue = "#081633",
    green = "#3d5122",
    orange = "#FF8800",
    violet = "#a9a1e1",
    magenta = "#c678dd",
    blue = "#51afef",
    red = "#6f3328",
}

local mode_color = {
    n = colors.red,
    i = colors.green,
    v = colors.yellow,
    V = colors.blue,
    c = colors.magenta,
    no = colors.red,
    s = colors.orange,
    S = colors.orange,
    ic = colors.yellow,
    R = colors.violet,
    Rv = colors.violet,
    cv = colors.red,
    ce = colors.red,
    r = colors.cyan,
    rm = colors.cyan,
    tr= colors.red,
}
  local color = mode_color[vim.api.nvim_get_mode().mode]
  if color == nil then
    color = "NONE"
  end
  print(vim.api.nvim_get_mode().mode)
  vim.api.nvim_command("hi! CursorLine guifg=NONE guibg=".. color)
end

vim.api.nvim_command([[autocmd ModeChanged * lua Pain()]])
```

Comment: Does [How do I trigger an autocommand when user enters/leaves command mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-do-i-trigger-an-autocommand-when-user-enters-leaves-command-mode) answer your question?

Comment: @MonsieurMerso unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried to use `autocmd CmdlineLeave * :lua print('left command mode')` and `autocmd CmdlineEnter * :lua print('entered command mode')`. After that I was able to see those prints in `:messages`

Comment: I've also found out that there is no `ModeChanged` event in neovim, are you sure that your autocommand works at all?

Comment: [ModeChanged](https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#ModeChanged) can be found here. Code works, i've been using it for a moment now. CmdlineLeave and Enter don't change the behavior.

Comment: what is your neovim version? `:version` output?

Comment: :version
NVIM v0.7.0-dev+916-gffd9551aa
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

Comment: Sorry, I'm using v0.6.1 and I don't have opportunity to build from latest. Regarding `ModeChanged` pattern, did you try to use different variants, as stated in the docs? For example: `*:*`?

Comment: Don't worry about it! Thanks for taking the time. I'm not sure what *:* does. I don't really understand the star part of my code.

Comment: `*:*` .. Formatting issue.